# how to use groupby function for making row to columns based on similar IDS

Tags: python, pandas

I have data which is in form of

```
arun 21-09-2017

raja 21-08-2016

arun 21-10-2017

raja 21-01-2017
```

i want my input to be converted as this follows.

```
arun 21-09-2017 21-01-2017
raja 21-08-2016 21-01-2017
```

Comment: This is pandas, right?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your data as an actual Python data structure. Preferably the desired result as well. Also it would be good if you added an explanation of the logic of the transformation you are trying to do. Lastly, it always helps if you post a bit of code of something your tired, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using pandas dataframe, you can then use *groupby* to get the desired output.

```
data = {'name':['arun','raja','arun','raja'],
       'date':['21-09-2017','21-08-2016','21-10-2017','21-01-2017']
       }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1.groupby('name')['date'].apply(list).reset_index()

Out[1]:
   name                      date
0  arun  [21-09-2017, 21-10-2017]
1  raja  [21-08-2016, 21-01-2017]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution bro.

Comment: @arunx18139 you're welcome. if it resolved your problem kindly mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: If your question was answered, please [vote on, and accept the most helpful one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You can accept an answer by clicking the grey check next to the most helpful answer and turning it green. Thanks.